# Debugging issue: why JE-command is "stuck"?

Tags: c++, multithreading, debugging, assembly, lldb

I have multithreaded-app but need to mention in the very beginning that target CPU has 8 virtual cores and totally my worker pool consists of 7 threads where one thread is "stuck" in the runtime on a simple if-condition like:

```
if (enumerator::e1 == data_member || enumerator::e2 == data_member) {
   return function_member();
}
// ...
enum class enumerator : char {
   e1: 0,
   e2: 'W' /// < 57
}
```

What I see if dig deeper:

```
    0x883c90 <+0>:   pushq  %r15
    0x883c92 <+2>:   pushq  %r14
    0x883c94 <+4>:   pushq  %rbx
    0x883c95 <+5>:   subq   $0x20, %rsp
    0x883c99 <+9>:   movq   %rsi, %rbx
    0x883c9c <+12>:  movq   %rdi, %r15
    0x883c9f <+15>:  movb   0x8(%r15), %al
    0x883ca3 <+19>:  cmpb   $0x57, %al
->  0x883ca5 <+21>:  je     0x883cab
    0x883ca7 <+23>:  testb  %al, %al
    0x883ca9 <+25>:  jne    0x883d08
    0x883cab <+27>:  movq   (%rbx), %rax
```

This makes me confused: as far as I understand `je` is just a jump to 0x883cab which is never going to be happened because `thread step-next|in|over` do not lead to anything and even later lldb(after manual break by `process interrupt`) is saying that execution still at the same point.

I have also noticed that stop reason is "next-branch-location":

```
(lldb) thread select 3
* thread #3, name = 'myapp', stop reason = next-branch-location
```

...but not really sure what does this actually mean because was able to google just lldb repo where this reason is mentioned just once at */Target/ThreadPlanStepRange.cpp*

Just in case:

```
(lldb) register read
General Purpose Registers:
       rax = 0x0000000002c8c000
       rbx = 0x00007fef312568b0
       rcx = 0x0000000000000000
       rdx = 0x00007fef31256988
       rdi = 0x00000000025662a0
       rsi = 0x00007fef312568b0
       rbp = 0x0000000002579b48
       rsp = 0x00007fef31256850
        r8 = 0x0000000000000000
        r9 = 0x00000000ffffffff
       r10 = 0x0000000000000000
       r11 = 0x0000000000000000
       r12 = 0x00007fef31256920
       r13 = 0x0000000002c5a030
       r14 = 0x00007fef31256920
       r15 = 0x00000000025662a0
       rip = 0x0000000000883ca5  
    rflags = 0x0000000000000297
        cs = 0x0000000000000033
        fs = 0x0000000000000000
        gs = 0x0000000000000000
        ss = 0x000000000000002b
        ds = 0x0000000000000000
        es = 0x0000000000000000
```

I thought about thread starvation but totally my app use 8 threads and virtual machine on the Intel Ice Lake platform in the cloud configured exactly with 8 cores.

Happy to learn something new, thank you in advance.

Comment: It's checking this `if` condition in a loop?  `je` itself will either be taken or fall through, not "get stuck".  (You can see this with `stepi`, aka `si`, to single-step one instruction).  So I think you mean it's stuck re-running code which ends up at this `switch` / `case` and never finds `al == 57`.  So don't write your code to repeatedly check something that won't ever become true.

Comment: Is your real question about LLDB's `next-branch-location`?  That sounds interesting, and I'm curious what it is and what mechanism it uses to break on that.  Whether it's just normal single-stepping with some checking done by LLDB, or whether it's using a hardware feature like last-branch-record or something.  But here it's mixed in with some thread apparently stuck in an infinite loop, whose source we don't see much of.